# laravel getting user inside controller middleware

Tags: php, laravel

```
function __construct() {   
     $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
                $this->user = \Auth::user();

        });
        echo $this->user;
        exit;
}
```

the problem is that when I echo the user inside the middleware function where I get the user his data is printed ok, that means he is loggeed in, but if I echo the same variable outside the function it is null, but the examples shows that it must be filled with data, what I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems issue of scope of the variable.

As you are defining and assigning value of varialbe inside function, you can not access it from outside.

Instead, if you do like this, it should work:

```
function __construct() {
     public $user = '';    // Declared it here,
     $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
                $this->user = \Auth::user()->role;    // assigned a value here,

        });
        echo $this->user;    // It will print here.
        exit;
}
```

The variable `$this->user` will be an object so I believe echo will not work. If you want to check its value then use `print_r($this->user);` instead and if you want to access it in some other function then `return $this->user` it.

Comment: I've tried to set it public $user = ''; - it says "syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)", even if without public it still doesn't show anything

Comment: Please try declaring `public $user;` inside class but outside contructor.

Comment: Can you tell me more, what do you want to achieve, you want to get all data of the logged in user or just one info, like `id` ? And where you want to use the value? In the middleware itself of in some controller?

Comment: I need to get the role of the user, to check its role in the constructor before any other function in the whole controller is executed, i tought it will be better if it is in the controller instead checking it in the router

Comment: Then why don't you just take the column which defines role. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the user inside middleware to set it in the controller. It is way better to do it simpler, same could be done in the middleware.

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->user = $request->user();

    dd($this->user);
}
```

This solution requires that the user has been loaded by `Auth`. This can be null at some point and for the route list generation in Laravel this will be called with a null user. If this still does not work, I do not believe your user is set or the Auth middleware has been initialized.